# How can I play instrument notes in a web browser?

Tags: web-applications, audio

I am creating a tool for a project where I take a data sequence and map characteristics from the data into musical notes and rests.

I need to be able to play whatever notes I want with a few different instrument options. I've written a lot of web based applications, but never had the need for playing arbitrary notes at runtime.

I know what I need, but have no clue what it's called or where to find it. I'm open to either java applet or unity3d libraries. Does anyone know of a library on either of those platforms that will help me? I don't have flash so that platform is out of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can play notes through javascript. Here is one app that does it: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

You can check out the demo for the api also: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/

There are probably other ways, but that's a start if you are looking for an example to start from.

Comment: Javascript would by far be the most preferable since it doesn't require an installed platform, I'll look into it.

Comment: It looks like it uses flash and html5 as a backup. I'm assuming it'll work though, I don't have speakers on this computer but when I get home and test it I'll mark it as the answer if it works well. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, html5 has extra features that the current one doesn't. The target date for it isn't until 2014, but most new browsers already support it.